# ¿Cómo crear una matriz de cadenas en C?

Tags: c, matrices

Tengo una función que debe crear una matriz de cadenas de carácteres y retornarla. He usado el mismo procedimiento para crear matrices de enteros de manera exitosa. Sin embargo, con cadenas, hay algo que estoy haciendo mal.

Mi objetivo es crear una matriz con la siguiente estructura:

```
[["pepe", "juan"], ["chucho", "manuel"]]
```

La función que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
//iMax vale 2

char **fillPreferencesMatrix(int iMax){
        int i = 0, j=0, x;
        //crear la matriz
        char **matrix = new char*[iMax];
        while(i<iMax){
            matrix[i] = new char[iMax];
            i++;
        }
        //llenar la matriz con datos del usuario
        while(j<iMax){
            x=0;
            while(x<iMax){
                
                printf("dame el primer nombre \n");
                scanf("%s", &matrix[j][x]);
                x++;
            }

            j++;
        }
        printf("%s \n", matrix[0][0]); //no imprime nada
        return matrix;
}
```

Así es como llamo esta función:

```
char **preferencesMen = fillPreferencesMatrix(iMax);
//ninguna linea de codigo se jecuta despues de llamar a la funcion
printf("checar si el codigo llega hasta aqui")
```

Comment: ... ¿Cual es el error que te sale?

Comment: No obtengo ningun mensaje de error. El codigo compila. Todo el codigo se ejecuta hasta la llamada a la funcion fillPreferencesMatrix(). Mi intento de imprimir printf("%s \n", matrix[0][0]); no imprime nada.

Comment: Ese defecto lo deviste poner en la pregunta, todavía no somos adivino(todavía;) para saber como ayudarte. Editala un momentico incluyendo lo problemas que tienes o el defecto, lo que quieres que salga por la pantalla y lo que sale, o simplemente di porque necesitas ayuda.

Comment: `new` es de C++. Entonces, para que lenguaje quieres que te respondan? C o C++?

Comment: Tu código es algo extraño decraras una matriz de cadenas con iMax elementos: [cadena,cadena], recuerda que char* es un puntero a matriz de char o simplemente un puntero a cadena, pero tu lo ves como tres matrizes: [[cadena,cadena]]. La solucion creo que seria agregarle en la inicialización la cantidad de memoria que quieres almacenar: char*** matrix=new char[iMax][iMax][buffer]; y eliminas el primer while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuyo que estás usando el mismo código que usaste con enteros.

Hay una sutil diferencia entre enteros y cadenas de caracteres. La diferencia es que las cadenas de caracteres están conformadas por varios caracteres.

Entonces el elemento de una matriz de caracteres no puede ser un `char`. Tiene que ser un `char *`. Así te quedas con un nivel de indirección adicional:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char*** fillPreferencesMatrix(int iMax){
    char buffer[1024];

    //Crear la matriz
    char*** matrix = malloc(sizeof (char**) * iMax);
    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++){
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof (char*) * iMax);
        // Cada elemento apunta a NULL inicialmente 
        for (int j = 0; j < iMax; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = NULL;
    }

    // Llenar la matriz con datos del usuario
    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < iMax; j++) {
            // Lees la información como de costumbre.
            // Bien puedes usar un buffer o leer directamente a la matriz.
            printf("Dame el primer nombre \n");
            fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
            int length = strlen(buffer);
            matrix[i][j] = malloc(sizeof (char) * length);
            strcpy(matrix[i][j], buffer);
        }
    }
    printf("%s \n", matrix[0][0]);
    return matrix;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##lVJNT8MwDL3nV1ggpO6LfYjbNg7AgUOHuHAaO2Rp2mVKkylJpbFpf53itN1Yy0AiqtrUfn72s816CWN5fi0Uk1nEYWJdJPTt6p7UTFIsmzYjVOJthK2oabfbEAspXw2PueGKcTujCNkGQjkQM7pt7Qng8WBYZjGi5sPB6G4xJoW93380HF2SQuoDdye0py5MW5jiRUrNAit2XMcQlP4WtMsU4yIo1gbKtBgwGONnUrjx1ulUZfhTks7F4hfeBm2Nel1Sr0/Ua6Q@wWrs87VP8PIWhiXP4Sg4lFydKwamFUTUaQsRl5DZjBqh/yXp7/pgD41Tq3iDE3VxcPVEUw5YAP6n3IDS6dJweFdXZ40okiXc2aCcZRf8MLvgt0c1cL4elJq4FRaFe4P3KqoBbLTswkz8SEqqRijSss1HcM7QhR9JDuT7fVR7Y7207jH5YIFPFWK4y4yqPGOCg/NSUipUUPX88sqPMP6Q5w/UOPKssYeahMJSMqMm4eSTxZImNu9hr6ZsOPwC).

Nota que en C se usa [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) es un operador de C++.

Si estuvieras en C++ sería más fácil usando [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Atu codigo, unicamente añadí la siguiente linea antes de empezar a llenar la matriz con datos de usuario: while(getchar()!= '\n'); Una vez agregada esa linea, todo funcionó  a la perfección.

Comment: @Elorriaga25 podrías haberlo agregado justo antes de llamar a la función también.

Answer (score -1):

Esta es la respuesta con la sintaxis que usé originalmente en mi pregunta.

```
char ***fillPreferencesMatrix(Person *(&listOfPeople), int iMax){
        char buffer[1024];

    //Crear la matriz
    char ***matrix = new char**[iMax];
    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++){
        matrix[i] = new char*[iMax];
        // Cada elemento apunta a NULL inicialmente
        for (int j = 0; j < iMax; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = NULL;
    }
    while(getchar()!= '\n');
    // Llenar la matriz con datos del usuario
    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < iMax; j++) {
            // Lees la información como de costumbre.
            // Bien puedes usar un buffer o leer directamente a la matriz.
            printf("Dame el primer nombre \n");
            fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
            //int length = strlen(buffer);
            matrix[i][j] = new char[10];
            strcpy(matrix[i][j], buffer);
        }
    }
    printf("%s \n", matrix[0][0]);
    return matrix;
}
```